# Construct custom object graph from xml

Tags: xml-parsing, deserialization

I have some xml files which conform to a schema which I want to read but in the process of reading, create an object graph which does not necessarily match the xml.

I know that if I just wanted to deserialize the xml that there are many quick ways of doing this.

My current attempt is to use an `XmlReader` and fire an event each time I see a new element. The challenge I'm having is how to manage where I am currently in the in-memory object graph in order to further build it.

If I have:

```
&lt;root>
  &lt;group id="1">
    &lt;group id="2">
      &lt;item />
      &lt;item />
    &lt;/group>
    &lt;item />
  &lt;group id="3">
    &lt;item />
  &lt;/group>
  &lt;group id="4">
    &lt;item />
  &lt;/group
&lt;/root>
```

When I get to group3 how do I know it's parent is `root` and not `group2`?

Ideally I'd like to create something like a `team` for each `group` and a `member` for each `item`. In memory, not another serialized stream.

It seems I need some kind of generic or object pointer which tracks my current location in the object graph.

Does anyone know a simple way of achieving this without having to construct a set of classes which know how to be serialized and de-serialized in different ways?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I have a `Stack<object>`. Each time I see a NodeType of `StartElement` I create an instance of my class which represents the read element and push it onto the stack. When I see a NodeType of `EndElement` I pop the top object off of the stack. Anytime I want to deal with the current place within my object graph I just `Peek()` what's on the stack.